# Android Ask the user to send crash log via mail

Tags: android, email, crash-reports

I have some apps already publish , but i want to implement this in my app, when ever my app crashes due to some reason i need the user to be shown a pop up to sent this crash log via mail?

is there any FREE lib to implement this?

Comment: Why don't you integrate Google Analytics into your app? You can configure to send crash reports every time your app freezes with stacktrace and all.

Comment: Why you need lib for this? You can write that log in text file and email that file to your email address.

Comment: @Analizer can you please guide me on that i am not getting how to do it

Comment: @jSumant how is that , you mean save it in users sdcard ?

Comment: You can find a detailed, official how-to on this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/.

Comment: @Analizer i need to implement only relatedd to crash logs how to do it?

Comment: @Goofy:You need to save on sdcard.

Comment: @jSumant can you please show me an example how to collect the crash log ? i can save it in sdcard

Comment: For being able to track crashes with it, you will need to integrate Google Analytics into your app. You'll have to create an analytics.xml and make sure it contains this line: <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>. But for this you'll have to follow the instructions at the link I posted (Update AndroidManifest.xml, Create your analytics.xml file, download Google Analytics SDK for Android v2 (with libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar included in your project's /libs directory and build path) ), Google Analytics app property and profile,...It's really easy and can be done in about 15 minutes.

Comment: @Analizer and after doing all this can the user send the crash log via mail?

Comment: You won't need the user, he will know nothing about this process, it is fully automatic, and happens in the background. You'll be able to track these events (and many more) on your personal google analytics page. But if you'll do that, please take a look at this page too: http://dandar3.blogspot.hu/2013/03/google-analytics-easytracker-detailed.html, as GA only sends part of the stacktrace by default (it can be annoying), but at this link you can find a workaround for that.

Comment: @Analizer thanks a lot one more thing when crash happens where the crash log will be stored and how can i get that file?

Comment: it won't be stored locally on the device, it'll be sent to your personal GA page and you'll be able to reach it any time (you can even filter them by date). But note that once you integrate GA into your app, it'll take time for the data to appear on your GA page (up to 48 hours I guess).

Comment: @Analizer No not that , generally say the app crashes where the crash log will be stored?

Comment: GA page -> all data -> reporting tab -> Engagement menu -> Crashes and exceptions submenu element, there you filter the dates you want to see and there'll be the crashes in a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [acra](http://acra.ch) or [bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) to achieve this.